# _rails_command:10: command not found: rails after installing through gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I installed rails using `gem install rails` and it showed installed successfully. But on doing `rails --version` I get `_rails_command:10: command not found`.

Here is what I get on doing `gem env`

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/rohanlekhwani/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/rohanlekhwani/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1_3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /home/rohanlekhwani/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1_3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/rohanlekhwani/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
     - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
     - /home/rohanlekhwani/.local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

On doing `gem list`, `rails` is clearly visible:

```
actioncable (6.0.3.1)
actionmailbox (6.0.3.1)
actionmailer (6.0.3.1)
actionpack (6.0.3.1)
actiontext (6.0.3.1)
actionview (6.0.3.1)
activejob (6.0.3.1)
activemodel (6.0.3.1)
activerecord (6.0.3.1)
activestorage (6.0.3.1)
activesupport (6.0.3.1)
benchmark (default: 0.1.0)
bigdecimal (default: 2.0.0)
bond (0.5.1)
builder (3.2.4)
bundler (2.1.4, default: 2.1.2)
cgi (default: 0.1.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
crass (1.0.6)
csv (default: 3.1.2)
data_uri (0.1.0)
date (default: 3.0.0)
delegate (default: 0.1.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.4.0)
erubi (1.9.0)
etc (default: 1.1.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.4.1)
forwardable (default: 1.3.1)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.0)
globalid (0.4.2)
i18n (1.8.2)
io-console (default: 0.5.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.2.3)
iruby (0.4.0)
json (default: 2.3.0)
logger (default: 1.4.2)
loofah (2.5.0)
mail (2.7.1)
marcel (0.3.3)
matrix (default: 0.2.0)
method_source (1.0.0)
mimemagic (0.3.5)
mini_mime (1.0.2)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.13.0)
multi_json (1.14.1)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-pop (default: 0.1.0)
net-smtp (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
nio4r (2.5.2)
nokogiri (1.10.9)
observer (default: 0.1.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.0)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.2.0)
power_assert (1.1.7)
prime (default: 0.1.1)
pstore (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
racc (default: 1.4.16)
rack (2.2.2)
rack-test (1.1.0)
rails (6.0.3.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
railties (6.0.3.1)
rake (13.0.1)
rdoc (default: 6.2.1)
readline (default: 0.0.2)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.0)
reline (default: 0.1.3)
rexml (default: 3.2.3)
rss (default: 0.2.8)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
singleton (default: 0.1.0)
sprockets (4.0.0)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
stringio (default: 0.1.0)
strscan (default: 1.0.3)
test-unit (3.3.4)
thor (1.0.1)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
timeout (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
tzinfo (1.2.7)
uri (default: 0.10.0)
webrick (default: 1.6.0)
websocket-driver (0.7.2)
websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
yaml (default: 0.1.0)
zeitwerk (2.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.1.0)
```

Just a heads up, as you can see by the difference in `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` and `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` ruby is installed through Homebrew, so not sure if that might be causing a problem.

PS: When I go into `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails-6.0.3.1` all I see is a `README.md` file

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. As supposed it was a path problem, caused due to installing ruby with brew and trying to access rails outside the brew environment.

Solution

1. Either add rails inside the linuxbrew environment to `PATH`
2. Install using `sudo apt-get install ruby-full` which automatically adds rails to path.